# How to write a query when pattern is in field

Tags: mysql, design-patterns, wildcard, sql-like

I've got a table in which a field contains pattern like 'hey *' or '%test%'.
Like this :

```
Id - f_pattern - f_Respond
1  - 'hey *' - 'hello there'
2  - 'how are you *' - 'am fine'
```

Is is possible that i write query like this :

```
select * from table where f_pattern like 'hey bobby'
```

and it returns the first row ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you give an example of rows that do, and do not, match, and exactly what your input match data is.

Comment: the sample table structure is provided in question , thanks ;)

Comment: This is just wrong. You should use table for data and query for matching rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you change your patterns to "like compatible" values, and reverse the like logic:

```
select * from pattern_table
where 'hey bobby' like replace(f_pattern, '*', '%')
```

Comment: +1, didn't know the `%` wildcard works in the field value as well!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
select * from `table` where field like 'hey %'
```

//edit

it surprised me, but this works:

```
create database test;    
use test;
create table pattern (a varchar (100));
insert into pattern values ('a%');
create table subject (a varchar (100));    
insert into subject values ('abc'), ('cde');
select * from subject where a like (select a from pattern limit 1);

-- result
-- +------+
-- | a    |
-- +------+
-- | abc  |
-- +------+
-- 1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: well , in you query , the pattern and wildcard is in your query not in field , In my case the pattern is in the table